# How can I get updates from a Firestore document? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following problem:

I have a document with data in firestore. I collect the data from that document and show it on the screen, everything is perfect. But, if I add data or modify it, how can I get the new data at the moment the document has been updated, without continuously checking if there have been changes? Since it would exceed the firestore reading limit. That is, it receives a kind of notification that there is new data, checks it and updates itself. I've tried with a state variable(useState) inside a useEffect but I can't find a way to make it work.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [listen to updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) of your data. If you are having trouble making that work, please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

first at all try to make a get right after your create or update action on the document.
If you don't want to do that, you can read this part of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) of firestore and try to create a custom hook calling it directly on the useEffect (in order to get every update in the lifecycle).